# how to subset by fixed column and row by boolean in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am coming from R background. I need elementary with pandas.

if I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

I want to subset dataframe to select a fixed column and select a row by a boolean.

For example

```
df.iloc[df.2 > 4][2]
```

then I want to set the value for the subset cell to equal a value.
something like

```
df.iloc[df.2 > 4][2] = 7
```

It seems valid for me however it seem pandas work with booleans in more strict way than R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here it is `.loc`

```
df.loc[df[2] > 4,2]
1    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64

df.loc[df[2] > 4,2]=7
df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  7
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was a quick solve. However I have another question if you may! Why I can't mix loc() with either names or index. In R I can refer to column either by name or index however here (in another dataframe), It requires me to make both rows and columns named?!

Comment: @Omar113 index you need .iloc for name you can using .loc , and if you want to mix , you can look at .at